# div value is undefined in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have one div in which the value is added dynamically using asp.net code behind. I want to use this value in my jQuery code but the alerts shows the value as undefined. The div displays dynamic dates like this:

```
<div id="test" runat="server"></div>
```

```
protected void dpchange_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   test.InnerHtml = Label1.Text;       
}
```

Here is the jQuery code in which I am trying to access the value

```
$('#addDialog').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 470,
  buttons: {
    "Add": function() {
      alert($("#test").text());
      alert($("#test").html());
      alert($("#test").val());

      var eventToAdd = {

      };
```

Comment: "protected void dpchange_SelectedIndexChanged" - is that C# or Java? Those are compiled languages that run on servers, not in browsers, like jQuery does. Could it be you are mixing up those two?

Comment: Have you verified that the test div is actually received by the client? You mention codebehind which i -think- is an asp.net concept, so i wonder if the server strips out the id before rendering for the client

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using ASP.Net,

you can specify ClientID property on div to be Static so that ID won't change during runtime.

```
<div id="test" runat="server" clientidmode="Static"></div>
```

Another way is to use below syntax

```
alert($('[id$=test]').text());
alert($('[id$=test]').html());
alert($('[id$=test]').val());
```

If your `jQuery` is on same `aspx` page, you can also use inline service-side markup.

```
alert($('#<%= test.ClientID %>').html());
```